# Adding data from dataset to datagridview table takes long time

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I am trying to assign large data ( about 230,000 row x 16 column ) from dataset to datagridview in a winform and it takes a very long time to be loaded in the datagridview.

After searching the web about this problem I found two solution to speed up the loading process, one using the virtualmode for the datagridview and the other solution by directly assigning the dataset to the datagridview datasource.

Both solution are working but still take a long time, as the 1st solution takes about 15 mins to be completed while the 2nd solution takes about 30 mins.

So I listed below the 2 solutions in order to check that I didn't miss something or maybe there is another solution for this issue.

1st solution

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
        this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);   
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.VirtualMode = true;
        this.dataGridView1.CellValueNeeded += new
        DataGridViewCellValueEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueNeeded);

        DataSet DSg = ACC_Data.Get_DT(File_Path.Text.ToString());

        for (int i = 0; i < DSg.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
        {
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(DSg.Tables[0].Columns[i].ColumnName, DSg.Tables[0].Columns[i].Caption);
        }

        this.dataGridView1.RowCount = DSg.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellValueNeeded(object sender,
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == this.dataGridView1.RowCount - 2 && e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        e.Value = DSg.Tables[0].Rows[e.RowIndex][e.ColumnIndex];
    }
```

2nd Solution

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
        this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);   
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet DSg = ACC_Data.Get_DT(File_Path.Text.ToString());
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = DSg.Tables[0];
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure, it is DataGridView which is slow and not getting data in DataSet in the first place?

Comment: yup, I am sure about it. :D

Comment: The question is: why do you want to load 230K rows in a `DataGridView`? Under the most likely conditions, the user would just be able to see 20-50 rows. What do you expect? Users to click on the scroll-down button over 5K times?! Wouldn't it be a much more sensible proceeding to load into the DataGridView much smaller amounts of data? For example: allow the user to search through the whole database; when the target lies in the 50000th row you can load to the DataGridView rows from 40000th to 60000th. Even when the top/bottom is reached, you might automatically reload more rows...

Comment: ... haven't you seen what most of modern sites loading lots of data do? For example: twitter.com. More data is being loaded as the user scrolls down/up, otherwise they would be tremendously slow.

Comment: binding of dummy table worked in seconds for me: `var t = new DataTable();

            for (int c = 0; c < 16; c++)
                t.Columns.Add();

            for (int r = 0; r < 230000; r++)
            {
                var row = t.Rows.Add(r, r, r, r);
                row[10] = r;
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = t;`

Comment: @ASh, it worked and loaded the data in about 20 sec! thanks alot.

Comment: @varocarbas, U r totally right as I was going to do this as my last solution, although the type of data I deal with needed to be full load and visual for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ASh, I just add a dummy table and bind it to the datagridview as shown in the code below, and it loaded the data in about 20 sec.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DataSet DSg = ACC_Data.Get_DT(File_Path.Text.ToString());

        var t = new DataTable(); 
        for (int c = 0; c < DSg.Tables[0].Columns.Count; c++) t.Columns.Add();

        for (int r = 0; r < DSg.Tables[0].Rows.Count; r++)
        {
            string[] Dr = new string[DSg.Tables[0].Columns.Count];
            int i = 0;

            foreach (DataColumn C in DSg.Tables[0].Columns)
            {
               Dr[i] = DSg.Tables[0].Rows[r][C].ToString();
               i++;
            }

            var row = t.Rows.Add(Dr);
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = t;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't think anyone scrolls and find a row from this big size data..
you should just get top 100 or 500 values assigned to datagrid and give a search option for rest of others using text boxes or whatever.

Comment: U r totally right as I was going to do this as my last solution, although the type of data I deal with needed to be full load and visual for the user.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualMode is fast itself. Here I have sample video showing VirtualMode with 9+ million rows (Northwind Customers table replicated N times):

[Virtual Mode Sample](http://www.screencast.com/t/zoLYvJXL6X6H)

Initial load of form takes around 8 seconds, and from there on it is fast.

IMHO, it is the dataset itself that you are loading slow. You shouldn't load the whole data at once, and that is the point of using approaches like VirtualMode. Unfortunately DataSet is born as a slow technology. IOW you should overcome the slowness in this line:

```
DataSet DSg = ACC_Data.Get_DT(File_Path.Text.ToString());
```

If you share ACC_Data.Get_DT() code then we might have suggestions on loading that faster (15 mins is really slow even for direct loading of a DataSet with 230K rows).

PS: I published the code for that Video here:

[Virtual Mode Sample Code](http://www.foxite.com/archives/vfp-code-vs-vbccode-0000286802.htm)